# JQuery .blur() Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

Basically, my Blur() function in Jquery is not being activated. My code is below and I'm using a special .notify jquery addition. I don't think there is anything wrong the actual body of the function but its more to do with the .blur() function itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  
  $("#verifypassword").blur(function(e) {
  var password1=document.getElementById("password").value;
  var password2=document.getElementById("verifypassword").value;
    if(password1!=password2){
    $("#verifypassword").notify("Passwords do not match.");
    }
    else{
       $("#verifypassword").notify("Passwords match!");
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The KGV Connection</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="animation.js"></script>
<script src="notify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function makeitpassword(){
 var passform= document.getElementById("passcontainer");
 passform.innerHTML="<input type=\"password\" class=\"signuser\"id=\"password\" value=\"\"/>";
 document.getElementById("password").focus();
 }
function makeitpassword2(){

  var passform= document.getElementById("passcontainer2");
 passform.innerHTML="<input type=\"password\" class=\"signuser\" id=\"verifypassword\" value=\"\" onfocus=\"makeitpassword2()\"/>";
 document.getElementById("verifypassword").focus();

 }

</script>
  <div class="signup">
<h1 class="signheader">Sign Up</h1>
<br />
<form id="signup" action="signup.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="signuser" name="username" value="Username"/>
<div id="passcontainer">
<input type="text" class="signuser" value="Password" id="password" onfocus="makeitpassword()" name="Password"/>
</div>

<div id="passcontainer2">
<input type="text" class="signuser" id="verifypassword" onfocus="makeitpassword2()" value="Repeat Password" name="VerifyPassword"/>
</div>

<input type="email" class="signuser" value="Email" name="Email"/>

<br />

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="logsubmit"/>
</form>
</div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Why are you using no jQuery when you load it anyway?

Comment: @mplungjan I guess a lot of people nowadays think that jQuery and JavaScript resemble the same thing.

Comment: **`WARNING`**, The snippet above can cause your browser to hang, it hanged IE11 on my machine when focusing the `repeat password` input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onblur isn't working because it isn't set to the password element. When a user clicks on your password inputs they get replaced by a new one with your `makeitpassword#()` functions. This causes the original element to be removed and the new element doesn't has a blur attached to it. Lose the onfocus events and you'll be fine!

If you want to display a message in the input use `placeholder`:

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="password here">
```